# Projection of an object in an image by using PCL and OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, pcl

Hello I am new to C++ and making a project by using PCL and OpenCV.

1. By using point cloud library with the data of point cloud how can I have the object's dimensions. (PCL)
2. After the object dimensions and necessery geometry of object how can I project the object in an image. (OpenCV)
   Any recommendation would be grateful.
   Thank you upfront...

Comment: opencv: `projectPoints` assuming you have the camera intrinsics (focal length can be guessed/tried, cx,cy have natural defaults, distortion all 0)

Comment: are you doomed to use opencv for 3D projection? Did you give open3D a try? What exactly are your requirements? Easy to use? Fast? Beautiful images? ...